# Insert contents of a file after specific pattern match

Tags: regex, sed

I want to insert file content at specific pattern match. The following is an example: add `file2.txt` content in `file1.txt` between `<tag>` and `</tag>`.

***`file1.txt`***

```
<html>
<body>
<tag>
</tag>
</body>
</html>
```

***`file2.txt`***

```
Hello world!!
```

I have tried following and it didn't work.

```
# sed "/\<tag\>/ {
h
r file2.txt
g
N
}" file1.txt

<html>
<body>
Hello World!!
<tag>
</tag>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may change `<tag>` for `</tag>`, as it is printing *before* `<tag>`.

Comment: I have tried `'/<\/tag>/` and it works!!! hurray..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try following command:

```
sed '/<tag>/ r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

It yields:

```
<html>
<body>
<tag>
Hello world
</tag>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT** for explanation why your command doesn't work as you want: The `r filename` command adds its content at the end of the current cycle or when next input line is read. And you are using the `N` command which doesn't print anything but reads next line, so at that time `Hello world` is printed and after that the normal stream of lines.

In my case, it reads line with `<tag>`, then ends cycle, so prints the line and after it the content of the file and carry on reading until the end.

Comment: is there a way to wrap content with CDATA?

Comment: I needed to add `-i.bak` to write in a file1.txt. `sed -i.bak '/<tag>/ r file2.txt' file1.txt`

Comment: Anyway to make this work with inserting after `<\tag>`? I tried using `<\\tag>` to escape the backslash but it doesn't work. See my question here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715401/how-to-insert-file-contents-after-line-match-while-escaping-backslash

Comment: Is there a way we can include the full path to the include file (file2.txt should be like /tmp/file2.txt). I tried this with escaping the forward slash which didn't work

Comment: @Birei is it possible to not print the 'Hello World!!' line, just inset the contents of the file. I can imagine how to delete this line with a second sweep of sed, the question is whether this can be done in one sweep.