# How to expand variable when using sed?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I'm setting variable `$hack` which I wish to expand and insert after the first line in [a text file](https://codereview.qt-project.org/gitweb?p=pyside/pyside.git;a=blob_plain;f=libpyside/CMakeLists.txt;hb=HEAD). The first line contains this text: `project(libpyside)`

Tried this:

```
$ sed -i "s|project(libpyside)|project(libpyside)\n$hack|" CMakeLists.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 124: unterminated `s' command
```

...and this:

```
$ sed -i "/project(libpyside)/ r $hack" CMakeLists.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 222: unknown option to `s'
```

...and this:

```
$ sed -i -e "2i${hack}" CMakeLists.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 201: unknown option to `s'
```

This is my `$hack` variable:

```
hack='#HACK: CMake with broken Qt5Qml_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS, Qt5Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
if(${Qt5Qml_FOUND})
  if(NOT "${Qt5Qml_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}" MATCHES "/QtQml/")
    string(REPLACE "/QtCore" "/QtQml" replaceme "${Qt5Core_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    list(APPEND Qt5Qml_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${replaceme})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES Qt5Qml_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  endif()
endif()
if(${Qt5Quick_FOUND})
  if(NOT "${Qt5Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}" MATCHES "/QtQuick/")
    string(REPLACE "/QtCore" "/QtQuick" replaceme "${Qt5Core_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    list(APPEND Qt5Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Qt5Qml_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    list(APPEND Qt5Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${replaceme})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES Qt5Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  endif()
endif()'
```

What am I doing wrong?

The reason I'm not putting this into a file is I'm doing all of this from within a Dockerfile.

Comment: this might be better than using variable... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715373/insert-contents-of-a-file-after-specific-pattern-match .. and `sed -i` twice is typo?

Comment: Typo fixed. `sed -i "/project(libpyside)/ r ${hack}" CMakeLists.txt` gives me `sed: -e expression #1, char 222: unknown option to \`s'`

Comment: You have to make sure, that $hack contains a regular expression in Sed syntax. Your example shows that this is not the case. Your question is not how to expand, but how to quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape the newlines so it becomes:

```
sed 's|...|...\
...\
...|' CMakeLists.txt
```

One way is to use sed for it:

```
$ hack=$'hello\nworld'
$ sed '$!s/$/\\/' <<< "$hack"
hello\
world
```

And in your case it seems you might be able to use `a`after instead of `s`ubstitute:

```
$ hack=$(sed '$!s/$/\\/' <<< "$hack")
$ sed -i '/project(libpyside)/a'"$hack" CMakeLists.txt
```

If that is the case then use a process substitution and read instead:

```
$ sed -i '/project(libpyside)/'r<(printf "%s" "$hack") CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the data into a file.  Barring that, try:

```
echo "$hack" | sed '1r/dev/stdin' CMakeLists.txt
```

(Note that this inserts the data after the first line, and completely ignores the content of that line.  From the wording of the question, that appears to be what you want.)