# How To Insert File Contents After Line Match While Escaping Backslash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to use code that I found here: [Insert contents of a file after specific pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715373/insert-contents-of-a-file-after-specific-pattern-match)

However, when I add a backslash to the code, it doesn't work. So, then, I followed the instructions here: [Slash and backslash in sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211834/slash-and-backslash-in-sed) to change the delimiters in `sed`. However, when I do that, the insert (which should be a few lines), turns into thousands.

Here's my attempt:

```
sed ':<\tag>: r file1.txt' file2.txt
```

Example:

File1.txt

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
```

File2.txt:

```
<thanks>
<tag>
<example>
<new>
<\new>
<\example>
<\tag>
<\thanks>
```

Desired output:

```
<thanks>
<tag>
<example>
<new>
<\new>
<\example>
<\tag>
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
<\thanks>
```

If you could please help me insert the file contents after a line match while escaping a backslash, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
sed '/<\\tag>/r file2' file1
```

I think you swapped file1 and file2.

Comment: I did swap file1 and 2. Fixing that now. But, I didn't get that output :-(

Comment: you also need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

Comment: yea I've tried that before `<\\tag>` and `<\\\tag>` both do not work for me

Comment: nevermind. I found that a line in my file was messing it up. you got it. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following awk too once.

```
awk '/<\\tag>/{print;system("cat File2.txt");next} 1' File.txt
```

To save output into File.txt itself following may help you in same.

```
awk '/<\\tag>/{print;system("cat File2.txt");next} 1' File.txt > temp_file && mv temp_file  File.text
```

Comment: Hey Ravinder, how could I modify this so that it would insert one line before?

Comment: @DomainsFeatured, please check my 2nd answer and let me know how it goes then.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as your other question (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720002/1745001), just print the new record after instead of before the target line:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{n=n ORS $0; next} /<\\tag>/{$0=$0 n} 1' file1 file2
```

I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Sounds great. Will try this out. Thanks again Ed :-) ....And, it works!