# Insert File Contents One Line Before Match While Escaping Backslash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I recently asked a similar question [How To Insert File Contents After Line Match While Escaping Backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715401/how-to-insert-file-contents-after-line-match-while-escaping-backslash) only to realize I need to do the opposite.

Using the code from that question, I have tried:

```
sed '/<\\tag>/i file2' file1
```

2nd attempt:

```
awk '/<\\tag>/{print;system("cat File2.txt");before} 1' File1.txt
```

However, I'm unable to get it to insert one line before the match.

Example:

File1.txt

```
Hello <[World!]> 1
Hello <[World!]> 2
```

File2.txt:

```
<thanks>
<tag>
<example>
<new>
<\new>
<\example>
<\tag>
<\thanks>
```

Desired output:

```
<thanks>
<tag>
<example>
<new>
<\new>
<\example>
Hello <[World!]> 1
Hello <[World!]> 2
<\tag>
<\thanks>
```

If you could please help me insert the file contents after a line match while escaping a backslash, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's possible in `sed`, but it's ugly and doesn't work if the match is on the last line. `sed '/<\\tag>/{r file1.txt; h; d; }; H; s/.*//; x; s/^\n//' file2.txt`

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for trying. I got this `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'` when checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{n=n $0 ORS; next} /<\\tag>/{$0=n $0} 1' file1 file2
<thanks>
<tag>
<example>
<new>
<\new>
<\example>
Hello <[World!]> 1
Hello <[World!]> 2
<\tag>
<\thanks>
```

Comment: Hey Ed, that's awesome. Of course, it works :-) You're the man. Also, just posted another question incase you're interested. I've learn more `awk` since you and I last talked :-)

Comment: @Ed-morton: That's clever. Nice one. !!

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: Go for it and mark it as answer. This will help other people looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In your `awk` solution you need to do following changes :
1. Interchange the file names as you've to work upon File2.txt and print the File1.txt contents where the match is found.
2. Remove the `print;` in awk as you don't want to print the `<\tag>` twice in your output.
3. There is no keyword `before` in awk. Remove it please.

```
awk '/<\\tag>/{system("cat File1.txt");} 1' File2.txt
```

Other possible solution is :

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{f1[++i]=$0; l=i; next} /<\\tag>/{ for(i=1; i<=l; i++) print f1[i]}1' File1.txt File2.txt
<thanks>
<tag>
<example>
<new>
<\new>
<\example>
Hello <[World!]> 1
Hello <[World!]> 2
<\tag>
<\thanks>
```

`FNR==NR{f1[$0]=$0; next}` Stores the content of `File1.txt` in array `f1`
`/<\\tag>/{ for(i in f1) print f1[i]}` : While iterating over `File2.txt` if the match is found then print the array contents.

Comment: The first one gives me an error. The second one works but the lines are out of order. Don't drive yourself crazy. I'm going to work around around it. You already helped me a lot today.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: What error are you getting in first case ?

Comment: `file1.txt: line 1: [World!]: No such file or directory` and 
`file1.txt: line 2: [World!]: No such file or directory`

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: I've done changes for 2nd solution which will maintain the order. Let me see why first one is not working for you.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, sorry. I will wait longer in the future. Missed a good opportunity to work with you again :-)

Comment: @EdMorton: Any idea why the first one which was similar to what suggested by OP itself wasn't working at his end. It was wokring fine my side.

Comment: My best guess is that the OP didn't execute the same command you posted but instead had some other command being called by system() because the command you posted cannot produce those error messages AFAIK.