# cat html structure from .txt into <body> of .html file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have looked across StackOverflow and haven't found an exact answer to my problem. I am no sed master so I would appreciate your help.

I have 2 files:

**header.txt** which contains the bootstrap standard header html structure:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

and my **Index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials on HTML and CSS">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,200" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>
<body>






  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my script: **addheader**

```
#!/bin/bash
catOut=$(cat header.txt)
sed "/<body>/ a $catOut" index.html
```

I am trying to append the structure to the body. (I know I need the -i option to actually append)

I keep getting an error with the $catOut because of the < tags in the header.txt file. It's trying to evaluate it or something.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown command: `<'
```

Comment: Wouldn't [Insert contents of a file after specific pattern match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715373/) be the solution?

Comment: It doesn't need to be sed, but it needs to append the contents to a certain part of the file. I think I can do it with a for loop but still need to figure it out.

Comment: Note that this is generally buggy if your text file isn't pre-escaped and you want to guarantee that the result is valid HTML -- things like escaping `&` to `&amp;` require HTML-aware tools. (If the body file *is* already HTML, using a `.txt` extension is arguably a bit misleading).

Comment: Thanks for the help Charles. That's great info, I will keep that in mind as I get better with using these techniques. This is mainly just for practice right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/<body>/r header.txt' index.html
```

`r` command reads the content of `header.txt` and inserts after `<body>` has been found. More about the `r` command in [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) or this excellent [grymoire.com tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37).

---

Solution using only `bash`:

```
reg='<body>' 
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    [[ $line =~ $reg ]] && cat header.txt
done < index.html > new_index.html
```